# how to find parent ascx value on child ascx

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, formview

I have a ascx control and i use FormView . On Child1 Control one dropdownlist and i want to find this parent ascx dropdownlist value on child ascx . Below is the code that i try but i am not getting the value . Always `null`

```
 FormView _parentView = this.Parent.NamingContainer as FormView;
               if (_parentView != null)
               {
                   FormViewRow _row = _parentView.Row;
                   DropDownList _ddlOrg = DropDownList)_row.FindControl("DDL_Organization");

               }
```

**Page is Like this structrue**

> Parent page -- aspx

```
   1child control - ascx
        2child control - ascx
```

i want to find 1child value on second child

Thanks for your reply .

Comment: @TimSchmelter on my child1 ascx page :(

Comment: It's still not that clear, where do you want to find the `FormView`? Instead of fiddling around with `..Parent...`, casting and `FindControl` i would provide meanignful properties like `Organization` which you can get/set from outside. Internally this property would change the `SelectedValue` of the `DropDownList`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i want to find Child1.ascx dropdown on Child2.ascx

Comment: As i've mentioned in my last comment, don't hardlink these controls via `FindControl("IdWwhichWillChangeSomeDayAnyway")` use a property.

Answer (score 0):

The big difficulty in locating the DDL is that you are using a FormView so the controls do not exist at compile time.

Here is a property that you add to Child1 that will lookup and expose the DDL when ever you want to access it.  This will be null until after you have called DataBind.

```
    private DropDownList z_DDL_Organization = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Expose the Organization DDL
    /// </summary>
    public DropDownList DDL_Organization
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.z_DDL_Organization==null)
                this.z_DDL_Organization = FormView1.FindControl("DDL_Organization") as DropDownList;
            return this.z_DDL_Organization;
        }
    }
```

To access this in Child2 control you need to first locate the Child1 control.  Because of the FormView the Child1 control will not be the immediate parent of Child2.  Here is a function to search up the parent chain until it finds Child1 and also some code showing how to use it.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Child1 c = LocateParent(this.Parent);
        if (c == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("Child2 does not have Child1 as a parent");

        // do stuff...
        DropDownList _ddlOrg = c.DDL_Organization;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Search up the parent chain to find Child1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Child1 LocateParent( Control control)
    {
        if (control == null) return null;
        Child1 RC = control as Child1;
        if (RC != null) return RC;
        return LocateParent(control.Parent);
    }
```